# If $\int_2^\infty f(x)^2 dx $ is convergent, is it true that $\int_2^\infty f(x)x^{-3/4} dx $ is convergent?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

If $\int_2^\infty f(x)^2 dx $ is convergent, is it true that  $\int_2^\infty f(x)x^{-3/4} dx $ is convergent?

Comment: Are there any constraints on $f$? I.e. is it integrable?

Comment: What if $f$ is not integrable? I.e. $1$ on rationals or $-1$ on irrationals in $(0,1)$.

Comment: @ZacharySelk Your example is integrable on $(2, \infty)$ :-)  But yes, you are correct, $f$ needs to be integrable.

Answer (score 4):

Let $p=q=2$ and apply [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality):
$$
\int_2^\infty|f(x)|x^{-{3\over4}}dx\le\sqrt{\int_{2}^{\infty}f(x)^2dx\underbrace{\int_{2}^{\infty}x^{-1.5}dx}_{=\sqrt2}}<\infty
$$
The integral is absolutely convergent and hence convergent.

Comment: What if $f$ is not integrable? I.e. $1$ on rationals or $-1$ on irrationals in $(0,1)$.

Comment: @ZacharySelk Your function is Lebesegue measurable and according to the linked wikipedia article  Hölder's inequality applies to measurable functions. So this answer still holds. But if you take measurability away I simply don't know :)

Comment: Just replace rationals with vitali set.

Answer (score 4):

$\int_{2}^{\infty}f(x)x^{-3/4}\,dx\leq \left ( \int_{2}^{\infty}|f(x)|^2\,dx \right )^{1/2}\,\left (\int_{2}^{\infty}x^{-3/2}\right )^{1/2}$
By Cauchy Schwarz inequality.
And the result follows.

Comment: What if $f$ is not integrable? I.e. $1$ on rationals or $-1$ on irrationals in $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**: Assuming $f$ is integrable.

Yes. This is the inner product of $f$ with $g(x)=x^{-3/4}$, which are both members of $L_2(2,\infty)$. One way to see convergence is with the [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) inequality:

$\int_2^\infty f(x)g(x)dx \leq (\int_2^\infty f^2(x)dx\int_2^\infty g^2(x)dx)^{1/2}<\infty$

Comment: What if $f$ is not integrable? I.e. $1$ on rationals or $-1$ on irrationals in $(0,1)$.

Comment: Also, on the right hand side, $f$ and $g$ should be squared.

Comment: @Bungo Thank you, fixed.

Comment: @ZacharySelk You're right, I assume in my answer that $f$ is integrable. Will edit to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $f$ is a Lebesgue-measurable function : Let $A=\{x:|f(x)| x^{3/4}|\geq 1\}.$  Then $x\in A\implies |f(x)x^{-3/4}|\leq |f(x)^2|,$ and $x\in A^c\implies |f(x)x^{-3/4}|<x^{-3/2}. $ So $|f(x)x^{-3/4}|\leq |f(x)^2|+x^{-3/2}$  for all $x.$

See Zachary Selk's comment and my reply regarding my assumption.

Comment: What if $f$ is not integrable? I.e. $1$ on rationals or $-1$ on irrationals in $(0,1)$.

Comment: @ZacharySelk.  Good point. Although if we are using Lebesgue integration and allowing complex values for $f$,  it still works for your example. BUT, for example,  if $S# is a non-measurable set  with $S\subset (2,\infty),$  and $f(x)=1$ for $x\in S, $ $ f(x)=-1 for x\in S^c$ then $f(x) x^{-3/4}$ is not  a measurable  function. I will edit my A.